# Create an associative array from the output of two commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

I am trying to create user directories based on an imported passwd file, and am trying to load the data into an associative array: array[username]=directory .
I can load the fields into a separate arrays but I cannot get the associations correct, as each field gets associated with all of the directories.

```
USERLIST=$(cat /usrmkr/in.out | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
DIRLIST=$(cat /usrmkr/in.out | awk -F ":" '{print $6}')
declare -A USERARRAY

func_StoreData()
{
    USERARRAY[$1]="$2"
    return $?
}

for ((u=0;u<${USERLIST[@]};u++)); do
    func_StoreData ${USERLIST[$u]} ${DIRLIST[$u]}
done

for i in ${!USERARRAY[@]}; do
    echo "making directory for $i in ${USERARRAY[$i]}"
    #Do stuff
done
```

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could read the whole thing with bash directly, telling read to split on colons:

```
declare -A userarray
while IFS=: read -r username password uid gid gecos home shell; do
  userarray[$username]=$home
done < /usrmkr/in.out
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
eval declare -A USERARRAY=(
    $(awk -F: '{ printf "[\"%s\"]=\"%s\"\n", $1, $6}' /usrmkr/in.out)
)
```

The `awk` script produces output in the `[key]=val` format required when setting multiple elements of a bash associative array, and double-quotes both the key and the value (`["key"]="value"`) in case there are spaces, tabs etc in either the keys or the values.

I've used `\n` as separator to make it easy in case you want to post-process the `awk` output with some other tool (although `awk` can do most things you might want to do with other tools, anyway).

Command substitution **should** be enough by itself...but due to what is, IMO, a bug in `bash`, if the first non-whitespace character inside the `( ... )` array definition isn't a `[`, it just produces the error message `must use subscript when assigning associative array`.

e.g. both of the following attempts to set USERARRAY will fail:

```sh
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ declare -A USERARRAY=($(awk -F: '{ printf "[\"%s\"]=\"%s\"\n", $1, $6}' /usrmkr/in.out))
bash: USERARRAY: $(awk -F: '{ printf "[\"%s\"]=\"%s\"\n", $1, $6}' /usrmkr/in.out): must use subscript when assigning associative array

$ UA=$(awk -F: '{ printf "[\"%s\"]=\"%s\"\n", $1, $6}' /usrmkr/in.out)
$ declare -A USERARRAY=( $UA )
bash: USERARRAY: $UA: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

The solution is to use `eval` when declaring the hashed array, as in the code example at the top of my answer.  Or,

```
eval declare -A USERARRY=( $UA )
```

Comment: 1. this uses `eval` - of course there's a risk of command injection.  I don't think it's a problem in this case, though, because my answer is intended for use with the OP's specific & presumably vetted/known-good input file.   2.  "*forgot to quote the expansions*" - huh? what?  I don't see any quoting problem - the awk code explicitly quotes both keys and vals for the array.  3. BTW, nearly 2 years later, bash v4.4.19(1)-release **still** doesn't let you directly use a cmd-subst or even a var in a hash declaration: `declare -A array=( $(...) )` fails with same error, so eval is still required

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If there's a quoting problem then please explain how and why - preferably with a real-world example using valid /etc/passwd style input, as is relevant to this question and answer, not just a generic and obvious "if you feed in garbage data, you'll get unpredictable and potentially dangerous results".

Comment: You've got a point that it would typically not be a problem for typical `/etc/passwd` data. So let me rephrase it: ⚠ while it should be OK for typical `/etc/passwd` data, that approach should not be used for arbitrary data as it would constitute a command injection vulnerability. Specifically, it assumes the data doesn't contain, `\``, `"`, backslash, `$`, `*`, `?`, `[`, space tab or NUL characters.

Comment: About the quoting problem, see  for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and the questions linked there to see what it means to leave expansions unquoted.

Comment: Note that older versions of bash had a bug  where 'a=("$x")` would fail to create an array with one element being the content of `$x` when `$x` was something like `[123]=qwe` (that was before bash supported associative arrays). It's true bash could have chosen to allow associative arrays to be declared as `a=("$x")` (where `$x` has to start with `[...]=`) in addition to the `a=([$k]=$v)` syntax but then, it would have had to define a way to specify keys that contain ] characters. In any case, I would not call it a bug but a design decision (here made by ksh where bash copied its syntax from).

Comment: 1. So, then, just the generic and obvious quoting issues that aren't actually relevant to this particular question with this particular set of input data.  2. I didn't **forget** to double-quote the `$()` or `$UA` variables.  That was **deliberate** - it would be worse than pointless to treat either of them as one big string, at best that would result in an array with one element. Definitely not what is wanted here. 3. RE: defining arrays with keys containing `]` etc - standard shell escaping and quoting seems to work as expected: e.g. `typeset -A array=( ["[foo]"]="bar"); typeset -p array`

Comment: 1,2. No, here you're using `eval`, you want that output to be passed as one single argument to `eval`. Invoking split+glob on it so that it be treated as an IFS-separated list of glob patterns resulting in a file list that `eval` joins with space before interpreting as shell code would not make sense whatsoever. 3. Quoting is shell code, surely you're not suggesting that in `a=("$x")`, the expansion of `$x` should undergo another round of shell code interpretation as if `eval` was called.

Comment: 1. Your concern is only valid if you assume the input data was random garbage.  My answer, as I have said before, assumes that it is not - that the OP knew what he was doing and had vetted and/or fixed the input data so that it was known to be good.  2.  I am suggesting that bash should do the right thing - i.e. do what is expected, without fuss, without throwing up stupid error messages and without requiring ugly workarounds like eval - and it should do that no matter what it takes, even if that means <gasp!> an extra round of expansion inside array definitions  (i.e. treat like a subshell).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than merging two lists, we can build the array in a single loop (and a single call to `awk` for good measure) by return a list of user:dir entries then splitting that up with variable expansions:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A USERARRAY

for u in $(awk -F: '{print $1 ":" $6}' /usrmkr/in.out)
do
  user=${u%:*}
  dir=${u#*:}
  USERARRAY[$user]=$dir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`zsh` has a more useful, more usual (similar to `tcl` or `perl`) way to declare associative arrays as a whole: `array=(key1 value1 key2 value2...)`

```
typeset -A userarray
IFS=$':\n\n'
userarray=($(cut -d : -f 1,6 < /usrmkr/in.out))
```

Doubling `\n`, like in `ksh93` removes newline's special status as an *IFS-whitespace character*. Without it, `foo:\nbar:x` would be split into "foo", "bar", "x" instead of "foo", "", "bar", "x".

With `bash`, the syntax is the same awkward one as in `ksh93`: `array=([key1]=value1 [key2]=value2)`, so you cannot easily get the output of a command into an associative array other than by using a loop doing one single element assignment at a time as others have shown.

Note that `bash` associative arrays (as opposed to `ksh93` or `zsh`) have a limitation in that the key cannot be the empty string (not an issue here). Another limitation, this time shared with `ksh93` is that neither key nor values can contain the NUL byte (also not an issue here).

(associative arrays support was in ksh93 from the start (1993), added to `zsh` in 1998 (3.1.5-pws-3) and `bash` in 2009 (4.0))

Comment: Why did you put '\n' twice into the IFS?

Comment: @rubystallion see edit